# How to write file with data is Uint8Array?

Tags: python

I have some problems write file ( image ) to folder.

my script I get Uint8Array() from image

```
var arrayBuffer = event.target.result
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
```

Then, I used "json.dumps", objData['imagedata'] is "var byteArray "

```
print(objData['imagedata'])
print("=========================================================================")
user_encode_data = json.dumps(objData['imagedata']).encode('utf-8')
print(user_encode_data)
```

[image]

Example image is print(user_encode_data) then I saved it in mysql with data type as longblob.

```
read_blob(1,"./MainArchives/images/data.png") 

def read_blob(author_id, filename):
   query = *my syntax query*
   ...
   photo = cursor.fetchone()[0] // "photo" is "user_encode_data" when I get back from mysql => as mentioned above *
   write_file(photo, filename)
```

And Finally is function "write_file"

```
def write_file(data, filename):
   with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
       f.write(data)
```

And i get error as: ==>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened the file in wb mode which means write binary data to the file whereas ur data is in str format. Try changing your data to binary format or if you dont want that you can simply do it by

```
def write_file(data, filename):
   with open(filename, 'w') as f:
       f.write(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way I can convert my existing data to binary format?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-to-binary/ have a look at this it might help :)